# Trouble to run kinect on freenect drivers - missing file warning

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, freenect, freenect-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to run kinect on Ubutu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic, NUC platform.
Im new to kinect/ros/ubuntu. I tried on kinect 1414 and 1473 but the same problem.

I install drivers:

sudo apt-get install -y freenect
sudo apt-get install -y ros-kinetic-freenect-camera ros-kinetic-freenect-launch
sudo apt-get install -y ros-kinetic-freenect-stack ros-kinetic-libfreenect

When i run roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch i get:

> [ INFO] [1492280709.082411279]: Searching for device with index = 1
> [ INFO] [1492280714.665412485]: Starting a 3s RGB and Depth stream flush.
> [ INFO] [1492280714.666609129]: Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 0:0 with serial number 'A70775X02149233A'
> [ WARN] [1492280715.435322495]: Could not find any compatible depth output mode for 1. Falling back to default depth output mode 1.
> [ INFO] [1492280715.504841224]: rgb_frame_id = 'camera_rgb_optical_frame'
> [ INFO] [1492280715.505093432]: depth_frame_id = 'camera_depth_optical_frame'
> [ WARN] [1492280715.553777273]: Camera calibration file /home/robot/.ros/camera_info/rgb_A70775X02149233A.yaml not found.
> [ WARN] [1492280715.554213275]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
> [ WARN] [1492280715.554572332]: Camera calibration file /home/robot/.ros/camera_info/depth_A70775X02149233A.yaml not found.
> [ WARN] [1492280715.555260541]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
> [ INFO] [1492280717.670423043]: Stopping device RGB and Depth stream flush.

In /home/robot/.ros/  ther is no camera_info catalog.

What im doing wrong?

I try this http://answers.ros.org/question/204572/trouble-connecting-kinect-with-freenect_launch/
but doesn't work for me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259749/trouble-to-run-kinect-on-freenect-drivers---missing-file-warning/) by [LucasM](https://answers.ros.org/users/30096/lucasm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akash ranjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/51626/akash-ranjan/) on 2020-02-09**:
did you get the answer for this problem. I am still facing the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a warning, not an error. Do you get data on the output topics?

The `camera_info` directory won't exist until you calibrate the camera in the kinect. See [here](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration) for how to do one form of that. The freenect driver uses a default model if you do not perform manual calibration.

If you are interested in just the depth data, you do not need to do camera calibration.

If you want to use the RGB camera combined with the depth data then you could do the various calibrations to try and improve the data, but it is not strictly necessary. If you want to use the RGB data for image processing, then you should do camera calibration to get a more accurate model than the default model.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4